# My renpy code just fails at working labels are broken menus are broken all things are just dead

Tags: python, renpy

My renpy code just dies. I try to use a menu and its empty despite having 2 choices they each also have no blocks of code despite clearly having their jumps this is the code in question.

Code in question:

```
    "Go to her house.":
    jump Go
    "Don't go to her house.":
    jump NoGo

#And this is what caused all the trouble. Just completely broke my game.
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using colons after the dialogue lines so I suppose that's a menu with choices. It coudl be caused by the indentation, the following code works fine to create a menu with choices:

```
menu:
    "Go to her house.":
        jump Go
    "Don't go to her house.":
        jump NoGo
```

You should include the error message though.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a menu statement so Renpy knows that you want the player to answer a question.

```
menu:
    "Go to her house.":
        jump Go
    "Don't go to her house.":
        jump NoGo:
```

Don't forget to put a label so Renpy knows where you're jumping to.

```
label Go:
        # Whatever script you have here.

label NoGo:
          # Whatever script you have here.
```